# Value of Double not correct when converting to Currency

Tags: c#

I'm doing C# examples via a video tutorial, I'm looked over and over this code but when I run it I find that the addition of "C" to make the value a currency on line:      `Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0,C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());` creates an error: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.*

I have checked the last line of code return `carValue;` which is returning "100.0"

I'm a bit stumped and don't want to skip, being from VB.Net I might kick myself for going *code blind*!!

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleClasses
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myNewCar = new Car();

            myNewCar.Make = "Mini";
            myNewCar.Model = "Cooper";
            myNewCar.Year = 2010;
            myNewCar.Color = "Blue";


            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",
                myNewCar.Make,
                myNewCar.Model,
                myNewCar.Color);

            //double marketValueOfCar = determineMarketValue(myNewCar);

            Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0,C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static double determineMarketValue(Car _car)
        {
            double carValue = 250.00; 
            //this would usually come from online but this is hardcoded for examples
            return carValue; 
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public double DetermineMarketValue()
        {
            double carValue = 250.00;

            if (this.Year > 2015)
                carValue = 200.00;
            else
                carValue = 100.00;

            return carValue; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `decimal` for all currency values. `double` is for scientific values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bare that in mind. As I say early days examples, finding it good to go from the  beginning and blast through most of it thankfully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting should be `{0:C}` (instead of `{0,C}`.

Comment: Thanks. Code blind it was! I wish the IDE would just say "Oi, comma!"

Answer (score 2):

use the following line

```
Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0:C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());
```

and in your function use decimal:

```
private static decimal determineMarketValue(Car _car)
    {
        decimal carValue = 250.00; 
        //this would usually come from online but this is hardcoded for examples
        return carValue; 
    }
```

Comment: explain why you think he should use `Decimal` - don't just state it.

Comment: Because (from the c# spec) `The decimal type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations`

Comment: @Loofer *I* know that, but people shouldn't say to use one data type instead of another data type without explaining *why* it is better. otherwise it's just cargo-cult stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the documentation - the only thing I can think of is you use a comma instead of a semicolon:

```
Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0,C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());
```

should be

```
Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0:C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Car's value: {0,C}", myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());
```

The error on this line is told you by the Exception: the input string `"Car's value: {0,C}"` is in a bad format.

If you check the [Composite Formatting Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn you will see that the error is at `{0,C}` which instead should be `{0:C}`

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Car's value {0:c}",myNewCar.DetermineMarketValue());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.